# How to show an Angular Component in a Thymeleaf page?

Tags: html, angular, thymeleaf

I'm trying to combine Angular and Thymeleaf or rather have to do so because I build a **Graph in Angular** and now need to implement the whole thing into an **existing Project**, which is using **Thymeleaf**. is there any way to 'easily' put it in the .html file of Thymeleaf?
I've started Coding only a few months ago, so I'll be glad if someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

So for i think it is not doable. How about using Chart.js to build the graph in thymeleaf page itself. Its implementation is simple. Checkout my answer here for reference 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58911896/10232467